# Centering the Image in Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

This is a shortened version of a larger XML file with only one out of four columns shown here.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <!-- 1st colum -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- 2nd colum -->
    <!-- 3rd colum -->
    <!-- 4th colum -->

</LinearLayout>
```

At present it is placed like this:

[image]

**My Questions**

**1)** Why wont the image center in the middle of the red screen area despite having used `android:gravity="center"` on the Image button ?

**2)** How to center it in that column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
android:gravity="center"
```

in your `LinearLayout`, and use

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

on your `ImageButton`.

This tells the LinearLayout to put its contents in the center of itself (vertically because of the orientation you set), and it tells the image button to center itself within the area it has been assigned.

Comment: Actually, I just played around with my own android code, and I don't think you even need 'android:layout_gravity="center"' on the image button. Setting the gravity on the LinearLayout accounts for both x and y directions.